# How can I make canvas size smaller

Tags: javascript

I created [this](http://rubin.cf/naam) with a wonderful CodeAcademy.com tutorial, and rehosted it on my site. I want to include it in my wordpress page: [http://Rubin.cf](http://rubin.cf/?page_id=21) but I cant get it small enough, so it creates scrollbars.

Comment: Did you try changing the width and height attributes of the canvas?

Comment: @MaxMeijer Yes, but to no effect, I tried changing the canvas size in html and canvas site in the javascript file: http://rubin.cf/naam/js/bubbles.js